# Hacer signo de interrogación con css

Tags: css, html5, css3

Tengo este código `css`:

```css
.icon {
      width: 80px;
      height: 80px;
      border: 4px solid gray;
      border-radius: 50%;
      margin: 20px auto;
      position: relative;
      box-sizing: content-box;
    }
    
.icon.info {
      border-color: #46b8da;
    }

.icon.info::before {
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      width: 5px;
      height: 29px;
      left: 50%;
      bottom: 17px;
      border-radius: 2px;
      margin-left: -2px;
      background-color: #5bc0de;
    }

.icon.info::after {
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      width: 7px;
      height: 7px;
      border-radius: 50%;
      margin-left: 37px;
      top: 19px;
      background-color: #5bc0de;
    }
```

```html
<div class="icon info"></div>
```

Con ese código que pongo lo que hago es dibujar dentro de un circulo el signo de exclamación, lo que necesito es de la misma forma con `css` dibujar el signo de interrogación.

Como podría hacer esto??

Comment: Puedes usar galerías de iconos como https://fontawesome.com/icons?d=gallery. El que buscas es como este https://fontawesome.com/icons/question-circle?style=regular

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esto es lo mas cercano a un signo de interrogacion que pude hacer utilizando solo CSS, como te mencionaron anteriormente, te recomiendo utilizar iconos svg o font icons, te facilitara mucho trabajo.

Para conseguir tu figura basta con darle color a los bordes de un circulo con background transparente, ademas darle un poco de rotacion con `transform: rotate`

```css
.icon {
      width: 80px;
      height: 80px;
      border: 4px solid gray;
      border-radius: 50%;
      margin: 20px auto;
      position: relative;
      box-sizing: content-box;
    }
    
.icon.info {
      border-color: #46b8da;
    }

.icon.info::before {
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      width: 5px;
      height: 20px;
      left: 50%;
      bottom: 17px;
      border-radius: 2px;
      margin-left: -2px;
      background-color: #5bc0de;
    }

.icon.info::after {
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      width: 15px;
      height: 15px;
      border: 5px solid transparent;
      border-top-color: #5bc0de;
      border-right-color: #5bc0de;
      border-bottom-color: #5bc0de;
      transform:rotate(-40deg);
      border-radius: 50%;
      margin-left: 27px;
      top: 20px;
      background-color: transparent;
    }
```

```html
<div class="icon info"></div>
```